# Circular dependency injection in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring java config for dependency injection. My code is somewhat similar to below code :

```
public class AppConfig {
    @Resource
    public A a;

    @Bean
    public B getB() {
        return new B();
    }
}

@Repository
public class A {
    @Resource 
    public B b;
}

public class B {
}
```

I am getting error "Error creating bean with name 'B': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:"

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: To construct A you need B. The circular reference is due to the injection of A into your AppConfig.

Comment: Have you tried setter-based injection instead?  That's the usual workaround for circular dependencies.

Comment: @Floegipoky how to do setter based injection with spring java config?

Comment: Why does your config need A injected? Could you use it as a method parameter instead?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-dependency-resolution  Look at the section titled `"circular dependencies"`.  There are examples below, unfortunately the docs still use XML.  The short version is that you `@Autowired` (or [@resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html)) the setter instead of the constructor or field.